# SSR rendering only the / url, only when I reload the home page (Angular 16 , Lazy Loading, Pm2)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, server-side-rendering, pm2

When I launch my Angular ionic application locally and refresh the pages (all pages),
I see these console logs.

However, when I deploy it on PM2 in production, my console log only appears for the home page.

I want to dynamicaly set og meta tags for Facebook on internal pages as well.

localhost
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQVyZ.png)

prod
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtbqg.png)
Here is a snippet of code from the server.ts file

```
const proxyConfig = environment.production ?
  require('./proxy.conf-prod.json') :
  require('./proxy.conf-dev.json');
console.log(proxyConfig)

export function app(): express.Express {
  const app = express();
  const distFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/monapp/browser');
  const index = existsSync(join(distFolder, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
    bootstrap: AppServerModule,
  }));
  const staticFolder = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/monapp/browser/assets');
  app.use('/usr/share/nginx/html/dist/monapp/browser/assets', express.static(staticFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));
  const distFolderCustom = environment.production ? "/usr/share/nginx/html/dist/monapp/browser" : distFolder
  app.set('view engine', 'html');
  app.set('views', distFolderCustom);

  const apiProxy = createProxyMiddleware(proxyConfig['/api']);

  app.use('/api', apiProxy);

  app.get('*.*', express.static(distFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    console.log('SSR requested for URL:', req.originalUrl);

    res.render(index,
      {req, providers: [{provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl}]},
      async (err, html) => {
        if (html) {
          const resCheck = await checkAndAddTags(html, req.originalUrl).then();
          res.send(resCheck);
        } else {
          res.send(html);
        }
      });
  });
  return app;
}
```

"I want to see console logs when I'm on internal pages and refresh them. It's about setting checkAndAddTags using setMetadata based on the pages."

Answer (score 0):

After a long day of research,
I just realized that the problem with my nginx conf

the good conf is

```
 location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

NOT

```
location / {
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_redirect off;

        # Universal rendering configuration
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```